# youtube api v3 - multiple search author + keyword

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

like this : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=rss&q=irem%20ya%C4%9Fc%C4%B1&author=ewakolik

I can search author and keyword together,

but I could not find it in v3 version

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=irem+ya%C4%9Fc%C4%B1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author was the YouTube user who uploaded this video. This translates to channelID which the video is uploaded in v3.

So in your search you can define [channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId= UC1oFl9_Y7LM5tjCcpTpqA1g&q=irem+yagci&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

To get channelId of any legacy username you can use:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=ewakolik&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```